# C# HTTP Server - Respond post request without processing post data

Tags: c#, http, post, server, get

I am currently working on a local http server written in C#. At this point I am not yet processing post data, but only distinguish between get and post request. In both cases, of course, a 200 should be answered. While testing the server, I noticed that if I send an empty post request, it is answered by the server with a 200 and an html page just like a get request without any problems. However, if there are images attached to the post request, as in my example, the connection to the server fails immediately.

I handle a client connection as follows. I know it's not ideal to store the received bytes in a string, but for testing purposes I haven't seen any problems with it.

```
private void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
{
    Byte[] bytes;
    String requestData = "";
    NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
    if (client.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
    {
        bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        ns.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        requestData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    }

    // Get Request out of message
    Request request = Request.GetRequest(requestData);
    // Create Response
    Response response = Response.From(request);
    response.Post(client.GetStream());           
}
```

And here is the method I use to determine what type of request it is.

```
public static Request GetRequest(String request)
{
    //return if request is null
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
    {
        return null;
    }
    //Split Request to get tokens - split by spaces
    String[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
    String type = tokens[0];
    String url = tokens[1];
    String host = tokens[4];

    return new Request(type, url, host);
}
```

Surely it must be possible to read only the headers from a get as well as post request and then still give a 200 response. Is there a rule of behavior for an http server on how it should handle post-request data?

Comment: The attached images should be mime attachments which start with a line that has two dashes at the beginning.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: That is the case, but my question is whether it is possible not to read the attached data at all and return a response immediately

Comment: A HTTP message is sent in a single piece and server has to wait until the entire message is sent over the Internet and is in memory on the server.  You do not have to read the body to send the response back to client.  The read in a memory stream occurs very quickly, but does use addditional memory and can be slow if you run out of memory.  What does slow the reading is if you are trying to write to a file.  You have a controller and what you want to do is to send a response before you deserialize the received data rather than wait until after you deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was quite simple in the end. The input stream of a request must be read completely before the server can respond to the request. In my case it was so, that I only read the header of the request to know if it is a Post or Get request, therefore the server could not respond to the request in case of an attached image, because the input stream was not read completely.